# somar e dividir resultados na mesma query pegando o resultado do primeiro sum

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu preciso de duas informações eu faço a primeira soma

```
SELECT 
FORMAT(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (12) AND classificacao = '3.6' THEN IFNULL(debito-credito,NULL)  ELSE  0 END)) ,2) AS custo_1,
```

Logo embaixo eu preciso pegar o resultado acima e dividir por um outro SUM

```
FORMAT(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (1)  AND classificacao = '3.6' THEN IFNULL(debito-credito,NULL)  ELSE  0 END)) ,2) 
/
FORMAT(ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (1)  AND classificacao = '3.1.01.01' THEN IFNULL(debito-credito,NULL)  ELSE  0 END)) - ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(periodo) IN (1)  AND classificacao = '3.2.01.01.01' THEN IFNULL(debito-credito,NULL)  ELSE  0 END)),2)  AS peso_custo_1

FROM tbl_balancete;
```

Como eu posso usar o resultado da primeira soma para não precisar usar todo o código da soma do custo novamente ?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizando um subselect:

```
Select Sum(Tabela.campoN+retSql.PrimeiraSoma) 
  From (select suatabela.periodo AS PrimeiraSoma
             , suatabela.classificacao
          from suatabela
       ) AS retSql
 Inner Join Tabela ON Tabela.classificacao = retSqsl.classificacao
```

Dessa forma, vc conseguirá fazer só 1 select com o primeiro valor (nem precisa fazer sum dentro) para poder aproveitar em qualquer outro pedaço da query.
Aqui adicioneio campo classificação apenas para fazer join com a tabela 'externa' apenas para exemplificar, o join tem que ser feito com o campo correspondente.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Poderia explicar um pouco melhor como posso aplicar no meu código, onde faria a divisão ? Não entendi direito

Comment: Agora, olhando o seu código, eu faria o select da tabela temporária 3 vezes passando no where a sua classificação e por fora, faria a soma e a divisão.

Comment: O carinha respondeu pesadamente.